# Strange behaviour offsetheight property firefox

Tags: angular, firefox

Building an Angular application. In a component when I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {

   console.dir(this.navigation.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0].offsetHeight);
   console.dir(this.navigation.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0]);

}
```

It logs:

[image]

However, when I look in the component itself (second log) it logs:

[image]

The 2 offsetHeights are not equal which is not expected.
What might cause this behaviour and how can I work around this?

Comment: Same issue, but still thanks for the tip

Comment: The second one logs the reference to the element, which will change when the element changes. Could you try to keep the first console.log and then log the offsetHeight again in a setTimeout? Might be something changing the offsetHeight in the first render frame after the ngOnInit, this would explain the change here!

Comment: Okay will try to look into that thanks!

Comment: Try logging the `offsetHeight` in `ngAfterViewInit`.